# Is there a java Set collection which ignores .equals

Tags: java, reflection, set

I'm doing something weird.  I want to create a Set, but I want to ignore the equals override on those objects, instead I want to do obj1 == obj2 for the equals comparison (really).

So imagine I have a couple of objects that look like this

```
public static class BrokenEquals
{
    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return 1;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

If I did this

```
    Set<Object> objs = new HashSet<>();
    objs.add(new BrokenEquals());
    objs.add(new BrokenEquals()); // objs.size() == 1
```

Obviously the Set will have a size of 1 (because the two objects are "equal").  Instead I want the set to contain the two distinct objects.

However, if I do this

```
    BrokenEquals obj = new BrokenEquals();
    Set<Object> objs = new HashSet<Object>();
    objs.add(obj);
    objs.add(obj); // objs.size() == 1
```

I would expect the size of the set to be 1;

I don't have access to change the .equals methods

The reason I want this is that I'm traversing an object graph with cycles. I don't want to be caught in one.

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`IdentityHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) and just ignore the values (the keys will form a set).

There are various implementations of `IdentityHashSet` available online, too. You could use Guava, for example, with [`Sets.newIdentityHashSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#newIdentityHashSet%28%29):

```
Set<Object> set = Sets.newIdentityHashSet();
objs.add(obj);
objs.add(obj); // Size will be 1
```

Mind you, I'd try to fix the classes which implement `equals` in a broken way, too...

Answer (score 3):

Kind of.  Java has `IdentityHashMap` which uses the reference to check for equality But it's a map, not a set.  For some reason, I don't think java has a Set version so the work around is to use the Map but put the key as both the key and value.

```
 IdentityHashMap<Object,Object> map = new IdentityHashMap<>();
 map.put(obj,obj);

Set<Object> set = map.keyset();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the class and override the `equals` method:

```
public class FixedEquals extends BrokenEquals
{   
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return this == obj;
    }
}
```

You can also create a wrapper class that implements `equals` correctly, and only insert wrapped values into the set:

```
public static class Wrapper
{   
    private final Object obj;

    public Wrapper(Object obj) { this.obj = obj; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        return this.obj == ((Wrapper)obj).obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: not possible.  The set can potentially contain every type of object in the class path

Comment: That would work fine.  But I'm going to go with the IdentityHashMap route instead just because is a little more compact.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Cogman. I agree that it is the more elegant approach of the two.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
public Class ReferenceSet<T> extends Set<T> {
    private class Entry<T> {
        private T reference;

        public Entry(T reference) {
            this.reference = reference
        }
        public boolean equals(Object that) {
            return this.reference == ((Entry<T>)that).reference;
        }
    }
    private Set<Entry<T>> data;

    /* Pass all calls to set methods to data */
}
```